# Current biohazard/disease outbreak dataset

Tags: api, medical

I am looking for api or dataset that shows *current* disease outbreaks and/or biohazards around the world. I have not been able to locate this yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDC
CDC Current Outbreak List:
http://www.cdc.gov/outbreaks/
Multistate Foodborne Outbreaks - Foodborne outbreaks listed by year
http://www.cdc.gov/foodsafety/outbreaks/multistate-outbreaks/outbreaks-list.html
Health Alert Network - Health alerts, health advisories, updates, and info service messages. Designed for public health and medical communities.
http://www.bt.cdc.gov/HAN/
Recent Outbreaks and Incidents - Events involving the CDC Emergency Operations Center
http://emergency.cdc.gov/recentincidents/index.asp
Morbidity and Mortality Weekly Report - Outbreak investigation reports included among other content. Note that outbreak material includes state health department investigations. Designed for public health and medical communities.
http://www.cdc.gov/mmwr/mmwr_wk/wk_cvol.html

WHO
http://www.who.int
Outbreaks and emergencies listed on WHO index page:
Ebola outbreak
http://www.who.int/csr/disease/ebola/en/index.html
MERS-CoV outbreak
http://www.who.int/emergencies/mers-cov/en/index.html
Emergencies
http://www.who.int/hac/en/index.html

Comment: This is good, but I am looking for an APi type of dataset that I could tap into in an automated fashion (think event + location in the dataset). Do you have any suggestions?